# how can i change the "Create new Account" to Custom registration

Tags: 7

Is there any ways to add more fields in "Create new Account" ?

By defaults it provides only username and emailid.

So how can i add more fields like gender, date of birth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields module should be enabled with Field UI and other.
http://YOURSITE/admin/config/people/accounts/fields - add field, mark "Display on user registration form." on field editing form.